# How to get UITouch to return a float instead of an int?

Tags: objective-c, casting, floating-point, integer, uitouch

I'm assigning the center of a view based on a UITouch. I read that UITouch returns an int value -- meaning that it doesn't give me the exact location of the touch. Is there any way to cast the touch value so that I get the unrounded location of the touchpoint?

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
 self.thumb.center = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where exactly did you read that a UITouch returns an int value? That's just plain wrong. Your code already demonstrates how wrong it is, since you already know that a UITouch returns a `CGPoint` value. If you look at the definition of `CGPoint`, it's made up of two `CGFloat` fields, so it's already a floating-point value.